# iOS: How do Core Data Merge policies affect NSManagedObjectContext Save and Refresh operations

Tags: ios, core-data, merge, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have been reading about [merge policies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergepolicy/merge_policies) and it gives me conflicting ideas about when changes are merged.

I am having two contexts - one in background queue and one in main queue. Both have policies defined NSOverwriteMergePolicy which I think is outright wrong. I am already having problems in sync. I often witness that in background sync from server data my NSManagedObjects are often outdated, and I end up saving them, causing loss of data.

Is there any place I could visit all the rules & order of precedence for context save, context refresh with respect to overriding policies?

I have seen all the documentation around merge policies but I am confused whether they take effect upon SAVE or REFRESH.
Also, up to some extent, this is very confusing. For example, [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmergebypropertyobjecttrumpmergepolicy) state this for `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`:

> A policy that merges conflicts between the persistent store's version
>   of the object and the current in-memory version by individual
>   property, with the external changes trumping in-memory changes.
>       The merge occurs by individual property.
>
> For properties that have been changed in both the external source and in memory, the in-memory
>   changes trump the external ones.

How to ensure that my desired properties get modified / remain unaffected when I choose to modify / not modify them on different contexts?

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR:** Merge policy is evil. You should only write to core-data in one synchronous way.

**Full explanation:** If an object is changed at the same time from two different contexts core-data doesn't know what to do.  You can set a mergePolicy to set which change should win, but that really isn't a good solution, because you will lose data that way.  The way that a lot of pros have been dealing with the problem for a long time was to have an operation queue to queue the writes so there is only one write going on at a time, and have another context on the main thread only for reads. This way you never get any merge conflicts.  (see https://vimeo.com/89370886 for a great explanation on this setup).

Making this setup with `NSPersistentContainer` is very easy.  In your core-data manager create a NSOperationQueue

```
_persistentContainerQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
_persistentContainerQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

And do all writing using this queue:

```
- (void)enqueueCoreDataBlock:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext* context))block{
    void (^blockCopy)(NSManagedObjectContext*) = [block copy];

    [self.persistentContainerQueue addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSManagedObjectContext* context =  self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext;
        [context performBlockAndWait:^{
            blockCopy(context);
            [context save:NULL];  //Don't just pass NULL here. look at the error and log it to your analytics service
        }];
    }]];
}
```

When you call `enqueueCoreDataBlock` the block is enqueued to ensures that there are no merge conflicts. But if you write to the `viewContext` that would defeat this setup.  Likewise you should treat any other contexts that you create (with `newBackgroundContext` or with `performBackgroundTask`) as readonly because they will also be outside of the writing queue.